# Spring and MongoDB: SAXParseException while reading Bean Definitions

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, shiro

I am using MongoDB with Spring, and Apache Shiro for session management. Since I encountered the same issue mentioned in **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10503101/spring-mongodb-and-apache-shiro)** question, I resorted to using MongoTemplate directly instead of extending MongoRepository for implementing Realm class required by Shiro. This realm is simply a DAO that deals with MongoDB for user & role persistence.

At the moment, I have a strange issue with the Bean Definition XML. It throws an SAXParserException, and I cannot comprehend why.

I have provided some information below. Could you kindly help me with this?

**web.xml:**

```
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    metadata-complete="false">
    <display-name>Test Web App</display-name>
</web-app>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo-1.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="persistencyProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"
        p:location="classpath:persistency.properties" />

    <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="persistencyProps" />

    <!-- Activate Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
    <mongo:repositories base-package="com.test.webapp.repository" />

    <!-- MongoDB host -->
    <mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host.name}" port="${mongo.host.port}"/>

    <!-- Template for performing MongoDB operations -->
    <bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" 
            c:mongo-ref="mongo" c:databaseName="${mongo.db.name}"/>

    <bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
        <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
        <property name="realm" ref="mongoRealm"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager"/>

    <bean id="mongoRealm" class="com.test.webapp.login.MongoRealm/>
</beans>
```

**Webapp initialization**

```
public class AppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME = "dispatcher";

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        container.setInitParameter("log4jConfigLocation", "log4j.properties");
        container.addListener(new Log4jConfigListener());

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(WebConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet(
                DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME, new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        // Filter for shiro
        javax.servlet.FilterRegistration.Dynamic filterReg = container.addFilter("shiroFilter", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
        filterReg.setInitParameter("targetFilterLifecycle", "true");
        filterReg.addMappingForServletNames(null, true, DISPATCHER_SERVLET_NAME);

    }
}
```

**Configuration class**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan( basePackages = {"com.test.webapp.controller", "com.test.webapp.util", "com.test.webapp.login"})
@ImportResource("classpath:persistence.xml")
public class AppConfig{

    @Bean(name = "jsonView")
    public MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView() {
        MappingJacksonJsonView mappingJacksonJsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        mappingJacksonJsonView.setContentType("application/json");
        return mappingJacksonJsonView;
    }
}
```

**Properties file**

```
# database properties
mongo.db.name=appkix_mas
mongo.host.name=127.0.0.1
mongo.host.port=27017
mongo.collection.user=user
```

**Exception chain**

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 49 in XML document from class path resource [persistence.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "class" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:131)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:118)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:294)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:203)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:617)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:446)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:385)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1603)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "class" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 29 more
```

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says it all:

> Line 49 in XML document from class path resource [persistence.xml] is
>   invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value
>   of attribute "class" associated with an element type "null" must not
>   contain the '<' character

Here's the line 48:

```
<bean id="mongoRealm" class="com.test.webapp.login.MongoRealm/>
                                  Missing double quote here--^
```

Comment: Aaagh! Kill me for being lazy / deer in the headlights.